# Edit many-to-many relations in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony2 with Doctrine and want to edit the relation between two tables represented with an intermediate table. The structure is like this:

Entity Tour stored in table tour

Entity Tag stored in table tags

I have a middle table tour_tags to store the two indexes per row: tour_id, tag_id.

And the entity definition is as follows:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="tour")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
Tour {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tour_tags",
   *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tour_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   *     )
   */
  private $tags;

  ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="tags")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tag {
  ...
}
```

As you can see I didn't put any relation info in the Tag entity.
This schema is working ok in obtaining the related data, tags for each tour and so.

But I want the user to be able to edit the relation info via checkboxes in the Tour form. I want to include a set of checkboxes, one for existing Tag in the table.
With this doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html it's possible to edit the tag names from the tour form:

```
/* The tour form */
Class TourType {
  public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    ...
    $builder->add('tags', 'collection', array('type' => new TourTagsType()));
  }
}
```

but not create or delete relations (table tour_tags).

I am looking for a way to embeed the relation (tour_tag) in the form so the checkboxes appear checked if there's a tour_id, tag_id row in the table.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

In your Tour class, add this constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

And in your TourType:

```
$builder->add('tags', 'entity',  array(
                'class' => 'YourBundle:Tag',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple'  => true
            ))
```

Comment: Didn't try it yet, what I did was creating and independent form to edit the relations.